# Long float of Local Box Collider Size and Center in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need the center and size of a box collider in world coordinates. So far I got this:

```
public GameObject Model;

BoxCollider m_Collider;

Vector3 Center;
Vector3 Size;

void Start()
{
    m_Collider = Model.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    Center = transform.TransformPoint(m_Collider.center);
    Size = transform.TransformPoint(m_Collider.size);
    print(Center + "   " + Size);
}
```

Unity prints out this:

> (0.0, 1.0, 4.4)   (0.8, 1.6, 5.0)

Unfortunately this is not precise enough as I need more decimals. How do I turn this into a longer float?

Comment: are you just trying to print more decimals? the variable itself will maintain the accuracy of a float. the print function just rounds for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: No I don't need to print them just wanted to know if I converted the local coordinates into world coordinates correctly. Thank you for your help. Didn't know the print function rounds variables

Comment: if you want to verify, assign the variable to the x-component of a transform or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately this is not precise enough as I need more decimals. How
>   do I turn this into a longer float?

It is precise. The problem is the `print(Center + "   " + Size);` or `Debug.Log(Center + "   " + Size);` functions. They are both made to truncate the `Vector3` values.

Just make a simple wrapper to show all the values in the Vector:

```
public class Logger
{
    public static void Log(object message)
    {
        if (message.GetType() == typeof(Vector3))
        {
            Vector3 vec = (Vector3)message;
            string res = String.Format("({0}, {1}, {2})", vec.x, vec.y, vec.z);
            Debug.Log(res);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(message);
        }
    }
}
```

and to use:

```
Logger.Log(Center);
Logger.Log(Size);
```

**Note**:

Do **not** try to pass `Center + "   " + Size` to the print function including the custom one above. This is because the the overload that combines a `Vector3` with a `string` also truncates it's value. Print them on different lines like I did above and you should get the full values.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```cs
print(Center + "   " + Size);
```

use this:

```
Debug.Log(Center.ToString("F4") + "   " + Size.ToString("F4"));
```

You can change `4` to another number, it represents the number of decimal values the method will print in the console.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: I thought of this as well, but that doesn't change the precision of the variable itself. Also, Center and Size are of type Vector3, so I'm unsure if it'll allow this type of conversion.